# c++ incorrect initialization of a 4x4 matrix in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code that runs fine  in debug mode but produces a bad output in release mode.
The code is straightforward, it simply creates an identity matrix 4x4 and writes it to the standard output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct mat4{
    float a00; float a01; float a02;  float a03; 
    float a10; float a11; float a12;  float a13; 
    float a20; float a21; float a22;  float a23; 
    float a30; float a31; float a32;  float a33; 
};

mat4 make_identity(){
    mat4 v; 
    v.a00 = 1;  v.a01 = 0;      v.a02 = 0;      v.a03 = 0;  
    v.a10 = 0;  v.a11 = 1;      v.a12 = 0;      v.a13 = 0;  
    v.a20 = 0;  v.a21 = 0;      v.a22 = 1;      v.a23 = 0;  
    v.a30 = 0;  v.a31 = 0;      v.a32 = 0;      v.a33 = 1;  
    return v;
}



int main(){
    mat4 Rm = make_identity();
    std::cout << Rm.a00 << " " <<  Rm.a01 << " " << Rm.a02 << " " <<  Rm.a03 << std::endl;
    std::cout << Rm.a10 << " " <<  Rm.a11 << " " << Rm.a12 << " " <<  Rm.a13 << std::endl;
    std::cout << Rm.a20 << " " <<  Rm.a21 << " " << Rm.a22 << " " <<  Rm.a23 << std::endl;
    std::cout << Rm.a30 << " " <<  Rm.a31 << " " << Rm.a32 << " " <<  Rm.a33 << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return  0;
}
```

The output in release mode is the same at every run and on different computers, that is, it isn't random.

```
1 1.4013e-045 0 0
0 0 1.1547e+014 0
0 7.63318e-038 3.46682e-039 0
0 0 0 0
```

I compile with full optimization enabled (/Ox).
Note  that if I disable the inline function expansion (/Ob0) the code works correctly.

I really hope that it isn't a compiler bug.

Do you have any suggestion that can help me to understand the problem?

My platform is:
Windows 7
visual studio 2010  10.0.30319.1

The generated assembly code in release mode is

```
int main(){
000000013F2F1000  sub         rsp,68h  
    mat4 Rm = make_identity();
000000013F2F1004  movaps      xmm1,xmmword ptr [__xi_z+90h (13F2F2260h)]  
000000013F2F100B  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [__xi_z+80h (13F2F2250h)]  
    std::cout << Rm.a00 << " " <<  Rm.a01 << " " << Rm.a02 << " " <<  Rm.a03 << std::endl;
000000013F2F1012  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (13F2F20B8h)]  
000000013F2F1019  movss       dword ptr [rsp+30h],xmm1  
000000013F2F101F  movss       dword ptr [rsp+20h],xmm0  
000000013F2F1025  movaps      xmm1,xmmword ptr [__xi_z+0B0h (13F2F2280h)]  
000000013F2F102C  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [__xi_z+0A0h (13F2F2270h)]  
000000013F2F1033  movss       dword ptr [rsp+50h],xmm1  
000000013F2F1039  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+20h]  
000000013F2F103F  movss       dword ptr [rsp+40h],xmm0  
000000013F2F1045  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F104B  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+48h (13F2F2218h)]  
000000013F2F1052  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1055  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F105A  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F105D  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+24h]  
000000013F2F1063  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1069  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+44h (13F2F2214h)]  
000000013F2F1070  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1073  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F1078  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F107B  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+28h]  
000000013F2F1081  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1087  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+40h (13F2F2210h)]  
000000013F2F108E  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1091  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F1096  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1099  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+2Ch]  
000000013F2F109F  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F10A5  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (13F2F2088h)]  
000000013F2F10AC  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F10AF  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F2098h)]  
    std::cout << Rm.a10 << " " <<  Rm.a11 << " " << Rm.a12 << " " <<  Rm.a13 << std::endl;
000000013F2F10B5  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (13F2F20B8h)]  
000000013F2F10BC  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+30h]  
000000013F2F10C2  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F10C8  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+54h (13F2F2224h)]  
000000013F2F10CF  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F10D2  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F10D7  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F10DA  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+34h]  
000000013F2F10E0  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F10E6  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+50h (13F2F2220h)]  
000000013F2F10ED  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F10F0  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F10F5  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F10F8  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+38h]  
000000013F2F10FE  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1104  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+4Ch (13F2F221Ch)]  
000000013F2F110B  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F110E  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F1113  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1116  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+3Ch]  
000000013F2F111C  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1122  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (13F2F2088h)]  
000000013F2F1129  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F112C  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F2098h)]  
    std::cout << Rm.a20 << " " <<  Rm.a21 << " " << Rm.a22 << " " <<  Rm.a23 << std::endl;
000000013F2F1132  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (13F2F20B8h)]  
000000013F2F1139  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+40h]  
000000013F2F113F  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1145  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+60h (13F2F2230h)]  
000000013F2F114C  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F114F  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F1154  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1157  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+44h]  
000000013F2F115D  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1163  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+5Ch (13F2F222Ch)]  
000000013F2F116A  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F116D  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F1172  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1175  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+48h]  
000000013F2F117B  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F1181  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+58h (13F2F2228h)]  
000000013F2F1188  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F118B  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F1190  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1193  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+4Ch]  
000000013F2F1199  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F119F  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (13F2F2088h)]  
000000013F2F11A6  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F11A9  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F2098h)]  
    std::cout << Rm.a30 << " " <<  Rm.a31 << " " << Rm.a32 << " " <<  Rm.a33 << std::endl;
000000013F2F11AF  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+50h]  
000000013F2F11B5  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (13F2F20B8h)]  
000000013F2F11BC  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F11C2  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+6Ch (13F2F223Ch)]  
000000013F2F11C9  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F11CC  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F11D1  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F11D4  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+54h]  
000000013F2F11DA  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F11E0  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+68h (13F2F2238h)]  
000000013F2F11E7  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F11EA  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F11EF  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F11F2  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+58h]  
000000013F2F11F8  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F11FE  lea         rdx,[__xi_z+64h (13F2F2234h)]  
000000013F2F1205  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1208  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (13F2F12C0h)  
000000013F2F120D  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1210  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rsp+5Ch]  
000000013F2F1216  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F20A0h)]  
000000013F2F121C  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (13F2F2088h)]  
000000013F2F1223  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F2F1226  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (13F2F2098h)]       
    system("PAUSE");
000000013F2F122C  lea         rcx,[__xi_z+70h (13F2F2240h)]  
000000013F2F1233  call        qword ptr [__imp_system (13F2F2180h)]  
    return  0;
000000013F2F1239  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

Comment: It can be a compiler bug because it works properly with any level of optimizations with g++ 4.8.2 under ubuntu.

Comment: You can look at generated assembly code to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Could not reproduce...

Comment: Works for me with VS 2010 SP1 (version 10.0.40219.1) both 32-bit and 64-bit mode, Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: [Don't see it](http://ideone.com/vSAt16).

Comment: Try clean & rebuild. Maybe you run some old binary.

Comment: Pinpoint the real issue -- is it that the `Rm` is corrupted, or is it that the `Rm` is ok and the issue is with `cout` not handling floats properly?

Comment: Does it make any difference to use `1.f` instead of `1`, and `0.f` instead of `0`, in the initialization?

Comment: show the assembly code for `make_identity`

Comment: @ Matt McNabb, `make_identity`  is inline

Comment: I managed to get working on VS 2010 SP1 (version 10.0.40219.1) so I think it's a visual studio 10.0.30319.1 issue. thanks Vlad

Comment: With g++ It seems to run fine: $ g++ -g -o /tmp/m m.cc 
$ /tmp/m
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1

Answer (score -1):

You could write it like that:

```
    mat4 Rm ={1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1};
```

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: This is a fine improvement of the code but is beside the point.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your code may b lack of assignment Operator / Copy Constructor. Which is defined in c++ objects by default but may not behave as required by the user's. You can try your code with including following in your code:

```
mat4 &operator=(const mat4 & in_put)                                                                                                                                   
{
    std::cout << "I am in Assignment Operator" << std::endl;
    if(this == &in_put)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        a00 = in_put.a00;  a01 = in_put.a01;  a02 = in_put.a02;      a03 = in_put.a03;
        a10 = in_put.a10;  a11 = in_put.a11;  a12 = in_put.a12;      a13 = in_put.a13;
        a20 = in_put.a20;  a21 = in_put.a21;  a22 = in_put.a22;      a23 = in_put.a23;
        a30 = in_put.a30;  a31 = in_put.a31;  a32 = in_put.a32;      a33 = in_put.a33;
        return *this;
    }
}

mat4(const mat4 & in_put)
{
    std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl;
    a00 = in_put.a00;  a01 = in_put.a01;  a02 = in_put.a02;      a03 = in_put.a03;
    a10 = in_put.a10;  a11 = in_put.a11;  a12 = in_put.a12;      a13 = in_put.a13;
    a20 = in_put.a20;  a21 = in_put.a21;  a22 = in_put.a22;      a23 = in_put.a23;
    a30 = in_put.a30;  a31 = in_put.a31;  a32 = in_put.a32;      a33 = in_put.a33;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the reason. There is no need to define any constructors or assignment operators here. Default ones just work.